# FullCalendar - Select Full day

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using [full calendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) agendaWeek view.
Now I want to select a full day in a click.
Something like we do in excel sheet [when we click on a column it select whole column].

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do something like this, depending on exactly how you want it to work:

1) Use the built-in "dayClick" callback for this. Anytime the user clicks anywhere within that day (but not on the heading), the dayClick callback is run, and you can use it to identify the clicked day and then do whatever you need to:

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
    alert(date.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
    $(".fc-day[data-date=" + date.format("YYYY-MM-DD") + "]").css("background-color", "red"); //make the selected day have a red background
}
```

N.B. If "selectable" is set "true", and the user *drags* (not clicks) it fires the select callback, not the dayClick callback, but this is a minor problem

2) In a similar way you can switch on the "navLinks" feature, which adds hyperlinks to each day heading, and handle the "navLinkDayClick" callback to tell fullCalendar what to do when one of these links is clicked:

```
navLinks: true,
navLinkDayClick: function(date, jsEvent) {
    alert(date.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
    $(".fc-day[data-date=" + date.format("YYYY-MM-DD") + "]").css("background-color", "red");
}
```

Note that both these solutions will apply to all views, not just agendaWeek. There's not a lot you can about that, unless you write a bit of extra code inside each one to say "only do this if the view name == agendaWeek" or something.

All of this information is available via the documentation (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/). I suggest you read it in depth next time you want to know if something is possible, as it will be likely to answer a lot of your queries immediately. There are also several demonstrations of key features.